# Selenium, TestNG, Base Class's method throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I have a base class in which I am initializing some protected variables and using these variables in some of the base class common methods.
Then I have test classes which are extended with the base class. Then I have the page objects classes which are also extended with baseClass.At this point, if I want to use protected variables from baseClass in TestClasses or PageObjectClasses they can be accessible.

I am facing a problem, I created a utility extended beseclass. In this class I am instantiating three-page object classes and creating some common methods using objects of multiple pages, I am performing some actions. `NullPointerException` occurred when in this Utility class I am trying to call a method from the base class

```
public class BaseSeleniumTest {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseSeleniumTest.class);
protected String browserName;
protected String tenantName;
protected String userRole;
protected String testType;
protected AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness;
protected static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
protected static ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait> wait = new ThreadLocal<>();
protected static ThreadLocal<WebDriverWait> longWait = new ThreadLocal<>();
protected BasePage basePage;

@Parameters({"profile", "browserName", "userRole", "testType", "areaOfBusiness", "tenantName"})
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup(@Optional("local") String profile, @Optional("chrome") String browserName,
                  @Optional String userRole, @Optional String testType,
                  @Optional("BMW") AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness, @Optional("Autohaus Huber") String tenantName)
    throws IOException {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    this.userRole = userRole;
    this.testType = testType;
    this.tenantName = tenantName;
    this.areaOfBusiness = areaOfBusiness;

    ConfigurationManager.loadProperties(profile);
    driver.set(createBrowserSession(browserName));

    wait.set(getWait());
    longWait.set(getLongWait());

    navigateToBackOffice(driver.get(), areaOfBusiness);

    //Login process

    // Instantiate page objects
    }

@Parameters({"browserName", "userRole", "testType", "areaOfBusiness", "tenantName"})
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeClassInitialization(@Optional("chrome") String browserName,
                                      @Optional String userRole, @Optional String testType,
                                      @Optional("BMW") AreaOfBusiness areaOfBusiness,
                                      @Optional("Autohaus Huber") String tenantName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    this.userRole = userRole;
    this.testType = testType;
    this.tenantName = tenantName;
    this.areaOfBusiness = areaOfBusiness;
    this.basePage = new BasePage(driver.get());
}

protected WebDriverWait getWait() {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
}

protected WebDriverWait getLongWait() {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver.get(), Duration.ofSeconds(300));
}


public WebDriver createBrowserSession(String browser) {
    some code....
    return webDriver;
}


@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void tearDown() {
    if (driver.get() != null) {
        logger.info("TearDown Called!");
        logger.info("Browser Closed.");
        driver.get().quit();
    }
}

    public void checkErrorPage() {
    String errorPage = MessageFormat.format(ConfigurationManager.getBackOfficeBaseUrl(),
        areaOfBusiness.getValue()) + ERROR_PAGE;

    if (errorPage.equals(driver.get().getCurrentUrl())) {
        logger.info("Error page occurred, redirecting to base URL");
        String redirectToBaseUrl = MessageFormat.format(ConfigurationManager.getBackOfficeBaseUrl(),
            areaOfBusiness.getValue());
        driver.get().navigate().to(redirectToBaseUrl);
    }
}

}
```

Below is test class

```
public class CreateNewInvoiceFieldsValidationTest extends BaseSeleniumTest {
protected InvoiceCreationPage invoiceCreation;
protected ValidationErrorPage validationErrorPage;
protected CreationDialogUtils creationDialogUtils;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void createNewInvoiceFieldsValidationBeforeClass() {
    invoiceCreation = new InvoiceCreationPage(driver.get());
    validationErrorPage = new ValidationErrorPage(driver.get());
    creationDialogUtils = new CreationDialogUtils();
}

@Test(description = "To test if the user does not check any of the title checks box and verify validation message"
        + "must be displayed")
public void tc019NewCaseFieldTitleValidationTest() throws Exception {
    creationDialogUtils.openInvoiceCreationDialogBox();
    //Invoice creation form
    //Customer data
    var customerData = randomCustomerData();
    customerData.setTitleIndexValue(4);
    creationDialogUtils.fillCustomerData(invoiceCreation, customerData);
    //Invoice data
    var invoiceData = invoiceData();
    creationDialogUtils.fillInvoiceDetails(invoiceCreation, invoiceData, CREATE, INVOICE_CREATION);
    //Click send invoice button
    invoiceCreation.clickSendButton();
    //Verify validation error message
    var errorMessageData = validationErrors(getErrorMessage("requiredError",
            "Title"));
    checkValidationErrors(validationErrorPage, errorMessageData, "title");
    //Close the form
    invoiceCreation.clickCancelButton();
}
```

And This is Utility Class

```
public class CreationDialogUtils extends BaseSeleniumTest {
    protected InvoiceCreationPage invoiceCreation;
    protected OfferPage offerCreation;
    protected RepairOrderPage repairOrder;
public CreationDialogUtils() {
    invoiceCreation = new InvoiceCreationPage(driver.get());
    offerCreation = new OfferPage(driver.get());
    repairOrder = new RepairOrderPage(driver.get());
}
   //some methods ....
problematic method is when i am calling 
public void openInvoiceCreationDialogBox() {
    checkInvoicePage();
    invoiceCreation.clickFormCloseButton();
    invoiceCreation.clickCreateInvoiceButton();
}
```

Here checkInvoicePage(); the method is in BaseClass which uses Variable areaOfBusines which gets null, and throws `NullPointerException`.

By Debugging I see when control passes to baseClass from the Utility class all the Variables have Null values.

Comment: And when exactly you expect to initialize the null variable? Because nothing calls `setup` on `CreationDialogUtils`.

Comment: I see that `CreationDialogUtils` extends from `BaseSeleniumTest` and setup method is called with `@BeforeTest`, so in runtime it looks like has not been called yet. Have you tried to call `setup` with `@BeforeClass` annotation?

Comment: @Yaroslavm I also tried to call setup with `@BeforeClass` but the problem is that `CreationDialogUtils` is not a Test class it's just a supporting class that performs some common actions for multiple HTML pages.